# Acer - Aspire 5742 wifi hard blocked with ubuntu16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, acer

I installed Ubuntu16.04 LTS in Acer-Aspire 5742 laptop. Every thing running well but wifi always hard blocked after 10-15 min.

1. I tried to add acer_wmi, wmi, wl to blacklist /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
2. I also tried to unblock using sudo rfkill unblock all but did not help.
3. I am ensure wifi is enabled by hardware.

I read multiple threads but no one help me.

Out put of command : lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57780 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1692] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] NetLink BCM57780 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [1025:036d]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
    Kernel modules: tg3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43225 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4357] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. T77H103.00 Wireless Half-size Mini PCIe Card [105b:e021]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

Comment: Is the wifi getting disconnected constantly?

Comment: No, when I start , wifi connected properly and working fine . But after 10-15 minute automatically disconnected and I see wifi is blocked by hardware and then unable to connect.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Try to install the proprietary driver `sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source`. This driver claims to support this adapter. Secure Boot should be disabled if UEFI is used.

Comment: acer aspire 5742 does not have secure boot option

Comment: after installation of bcmwl-kernel-source same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reactivate your wifi by using

```
sudo rfkill unblock wifi
```

Comment: in question i mention already used, it did not help